# Validating field inside a PopUp in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, actionscript-2, flex4.5

I have a popup which open on CheckBox clicked, I want to validate the field inside checkBox.

```js
public function validatePopUp():Boolean{
    trace("validatePopUp");
    validatorPopUp = new ArrayCollection();
    validatorPopUp.addItem(iecCode_validator);
    validatorPopUp.addItem(branchno_validator);
    trace("validatorPopUp.length"+validatorPopUp.length);
    var valid:Boolean = true;
    for each(var validator:Validator in validatorPopUp){
     var VRE:ValidationResultEvent = validator.validate();
     if(VRE.type != ValidationResultEvent.VALID){
      valid = false;
      trace("valid = false");
     }
    }
    trace("validtrue");
    return valid;
   }
```

And before Save button Click I am calling this function. This is working for popup open on button click & popup open on ComboBox value selected, but for Check Box I am getting this error.

> ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property selectedItem not found on spark.components.CheckBox and there is no default value.
>       at mx.validators::Validator/getValueFromSource()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\validators\Validator.as:980]
>       at mx.validators::Validator/validate()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\validators\Validator.as:940]
>       at mx.validators::Validator/triggerHandler()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\validators\Validator.as:1167]
>       at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
>       at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
>       at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()

Answer (score 0):

You set Validator.property = "selectedItem" when you created one of the Validators.  Then you are trying to have it validate a CheckBox (which does not have a property named "selectedItem") so it will throw that error.

Now as to what you are trying to do... it sounds like (from this statement "I want to Validate the field inside checkBox .") you want to know which one of several checkboxes is checked.  If this is the case, you should use a [RadioButtonGroup](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/RadioButtonGroup.html) instead of CheckBoxes. You could even skin them so they look like checkboxes if this is a desire / requirement.

But, if you are trying to validate that a checkbox is checked (required), then you could easily check it directly without a validator (checkbook.selected == true)

Comment: First Of all Thnx 4 rplying.Actually m trying to open a popup on checkbox Clicked & inside the popup m having some textfield,CmbBox which i want to validate if ny field null value popup should not close & it should show error msg on particular field.                                                My above code working fine for popup open on CmbBox item selected. For Eg:- Inside popup m hvnig 2 textfield which is validated the popup opening time m getting the error message.....

Comment: then you have a reference problem somewhere because that error is definitely thrown because your validator is trying to validate the CheckBox itself which has no "selectedItem" property.  I bet you'll find an "event.target" or copy/paste error that is wrongly telling your validator to validate the checkbox.

Comment: Thnx 4 ur help got the problm ...it was clean & build Problem.